# in the below data how can i write query ,for counting number of employees having skill html?

Tags: hive

```
var myMenu  = $( `
    <menu type="context" id="table">
    </menu>
` ).appendTo ("body");


id name skill
1  abc  html,java,css
2  xyz  html,c,other
```

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) (Use a *code block* (indent lines four spaces, or mark and use "the {}-button" from the post editor's tool bar) for multi-line code. I prefer *block quotes* (prepend "> " or use the button) for machine in-/output.) Please capitalise carefully. Where have you already looked for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following query.

```
select count(*) from yourtable where find_in_set("html",skill) > 0;
```

find_in_set from Hive documentation

> Returns the first occurance of str in strList where strList is a
>   comma-delimited string. Returns null if either argument is null.
>   Returns 0 if the first argument contains any commas. For example,
>   find_in_set('ab', 'abc,b,ab,c,def') returns 3.

Comment: can you pls explain what is find_in_set here??

Comment: select explode (skill as skillset) from table name;  after this if i create another table and load this table data and then if i write query like select count(empno),skill from table name group by skill having skill="html",this will work please clear me